# JavaScript nested promise scoping and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a real problem with JavaScript promises that I've been trying to solve for the last few hours and I just can't seem to fix it. My experience with promises is limited so I'm open to the idea that my approach is simply incorrect.

Right now I'm building an app that requires a two-step process:

1. Connect to an external PaaS service, which returns a promise
2. Within that promise, retrieve some data

Here's a sample of a factory I created:

```
app.factory('serviceFactory', [
    function() {
        var getData = function getData() {
            service.connect(apiKey).then(function() {
                    service.getData('dataStore').then(function(result) {
                        // Retrieve data
                        return result;
                    }, errorFunction);
                },
                errorFunction);
        };
        return {
                getData: getData
        };
    }

]);
```

As you can see, there are nested promises here. What's causing me problems is when I try to use the data from the most deeply-nested promise within an AngularJS view. Specifically, I want to use the data from that promise in an `ng-repeat` statement. But no matter what I try, it just won't show up. I've attempted to assign data within the promise instead of returning, like so:

```
service.getData('dataStore').then(function(result) {
    // Retrieve data
    // Assigned the enclosing scope's this to 'self'
    self.data = result;
}, errorFunction);
```

That doesn't work either. I've tried a variety of other approaches, but I just can't seem to get that data to the view. There's no problem getting it to show up in a `console.log(data)`call, so I know the data is coming back correctly. Does anyone have experience solving a problem like this?

Comment: You don't show how the service is getting the data, but this sounds like you need to call $scope.$apply() wherever this is getting used,

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little bit?

Comment: Well, typically if you are calling a service using $http at some point, angular takes care of the digest cycle for you. But if you are using something else (a non-angular method) to get the data, you have to manually initiate a digest using $apply so Angular knows data has arrived.

Comment: You need to `return` the promise generated by `service.connect().then()` as the result of `getData` (btw, what is this `service`?)

Comment: Can you show the code that uses serviceFactory.getData() in your controller?

Comment: In your plunkr, at line 16, if you console.log(result) does it log data? What happens if you self.DataArr = result?

Comment: That was something I forgot to change back for the plunkr. To answer your questions: A) yes, I get the data I'm looking for in the console, and B) when I do that I still can't access the data in my view.

Comment: First thing I would do is add a $scope.$apply() right after that line then, and if that doesn't work, need to take a look at how you are setting up the repeat in your HTML. If you do an apply you will need to pass in $scope to your controller.

Comment: Tried the `$scope.apply()` method and it didn't work. The `ng-repeat` I setup to test this is pretty basic: `<div ng-repeat="i in app.dataArr">{{ i }}</div>`. I placed some dummy elements into it outside of the promises and they show up without a problem.

Comment: Are you using the controllerAs syntax? As in, somewhere in your HTML outside the ng-repeat you have a ng-controller="DataController as app"? I'm assuming app because you said app.dataArr.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `controllerAs` syntax within a directive. I updated the plunkr with the directive's definition if you want to check that out. I called the controller `myApp` in the plunkr because `app` was already taken.

Comment: In that particular code I think your ng-repeat should be ng-repeat="i in myApp.dataArr". Would be helpful to see the HTML.

Comment: OK, I added the HTML I'm using in the plunkr.

Comment: [I scaffold-ed out a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxACLULl1LdYdlsPPpjI?p=preview). Maybe you can compare what you are doing with it and see where you might be going wrong. There were two issues I saw; first, your directive doesn't have a template. Second, when using a directive called myApp in your HTML it should be written as my-app.

Comment: That plunkr does allow values to get passed from the factory to the controller, but it doesn't help much with the promises I have to deal with. I still get the same problem where I can see the values I need within the promises, but the view simply does not have access to the data. I do appreciate your efforts though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you'll try to avoid nested promises. You can take a look at [this blog post](http://fedsmemoirs.com/2015/02/08/chain-your-promises-no-more-promise-soup/), which will let you see how you can avoid 'promise soup' and have promise chaining instead.

As for your question, I would recommend the following:

A quick solution will be to fix your problem. You are returning the factory method wrong:

```
app.factory('serviceFactory', [
    function() {
        var getData = function getData() {
            return service.connect(apiKey).then(function() {
                    service.getData('dataStore').then(function(result) {
                        // Retrieve data
                        return result;
                    }, errorFunction);
                },
                errorFunction);
        };//here you should close the 'getData method
        return {
            getData: getData
        };   
    }
]);
```

But, you can refactor your code to chain your promises. Something like:

```
app.factory('serviceFactory', [
    function() {
        var connect = function connect() {
            return service.connect(apiKey);
        };
        var getData = function getData(data) {
            return service.getData(data);
        };       
        return {
            getData: getData,
            connect: connect
        };
    }
]);
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
serviceFactory.connect(apiKey)
     .then(serviceFactory.getData)
     .then(function(result){
           //use data here
      })
```

All of this should be tested - you can add a plunker or jsbin if you want a working solution...

**EDIT**

I think that you have another problem here. You are mixing between `serviceFactory` and `service`. I'm not sure that I understand if this is the same service, or which is who. Can you provide a more detailed code or add plunker/jsbin etc.

Comment: I'll try chaining, but I see now that I just entered the code incorrectly for my question. The return statement is actually outside of getData, so that's not the problem. I'll edit it to reflect that.

Comment: Please take a look at my chaining solution. If you want a quick solution, without chaining, you can just add a 'return' to  your 'service.connect'. But promises are all about avoiding this callback hell...

Comment: Please pay attention to the `return`, in the  `return service.connect(apiKey).then(function() {` ,in my first solution

Comment: I realize my wording could have been better here, especially since the concept of 'services' exists in Angular. To clarify, 'serviceFactory' is the factory that holds the promises, and 'service' is the PaaS service I'm connecting to.

Comment: Please take a look at my final edit. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: I refactored my code to use chaining and, although it looks much cleaner, I still can't access the data within the last promise call in a view. I can do a console.log() call and get the data no problem, but I can't use it.

Comment: I am glad you refactored your code. This is important. Can you look at my last edit please? Can you provide more details / plunker? Maybe you have an error? Can you console.log inside the error callbacks?

Comment: There aren't any errors - I can get the objects I need within the scope of the then statements, just not outside. I've created a small punker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Xs6ksUVWG5N6iEfgzGr). The project I'm working on isn't public, but this should be enough to give you an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

I've edited this answer, which I originally deleted because I didn't explain what I meant very clearly and it garnered some downvotes (without explanation, but that's my guess). Anyway, here is a more complete answer.

I suspect that your problem is that whatever PaaS you are using has no awareness of Angular, and Angular likewise has no awareness of the PaaS. You say in your question that the PaaS has methods that return promises, but if Angular is not aware of those promises, then, when the promises resolve, Angular does not know to update the DOM. Angular does this via the digest cycle which is where Angular checks everything that it is watching to see if it has changed. When using `$q` (or other Angular services like `$http`), Angular knows to automatically kick off a digest cycle when they resolve. It does not, however, kick off a digest cycle when promises created by other means resolve.

This is what I think is happening in your code. Your PaaS is giving you promises, which are resolving properly (you said you can see the results via console), but your HTML is not being updated.

[I modified the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxACLULl1LdYdlsPPpjI?p=preview) we were working on to demonstrate this in action. I created a mock PaaS (not knowing what you are using) that creates promises using `jQuery` and resolves them. As you can see, when the promises resolve, the result is logged to the console, but the DOM is not resolved.

```
angular.module("app",[])
  .value("mockPaaS", mockPaaS)
  .factory("dataFactory", function($q, mockPaaS){

    function getData(){
      return mockPaaS.connect()
        .then(mockPaaS.getData);
    }
    return {
      getData: getData
    }
  })
  .controller("DataController", function (dataFactory) {
      var vm = this;
      dataFactory.getData().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        vm.dataArr = result;
      });
  })
  .directive("myApp", function(){
      return {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: "DataController",
        controllerAs: 'myApp',
        template: "<div ng-repeat='i in myApp.dataArr'>{{i}}</div>"
    };
  });
```

I was originally suggesting that you could solve this problem by adding a `$scope.$apply()` after you capture the result of the promise. I've forked the Plunker and you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R4heDnOvmRpborCCv4Y0?p=preview) it does, in fact update the DOM.

```
  .controller("DataController", function ($scope, dataFactory) {
      var vm = this;
      dataFactory.getData().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        vm.dataArr = result;
        $scope.$apply();
      });
  })
```

There is, however, a more idiomatic solution. When you get a promise from outside angular that you need to use in Angular, [you can wrap that promise using $q.when](http://plnkr.co/edit/45wWF2tfUnjlkV9kXZwa?p=preview) (an Angular aware promise), and when the external promise resolves, Angular should kick off it's digest cycle naturally.

```
  .factory("dataFactory", function($q, mockPaaS){
    function getData(){
      return $q.when(mockPaaS.connect()
        .then(mockPaaS.getData));
    }
    return {
      getData: getData
    }
  })
  .controller("DataController", function (dataFactory) {
      var vm = this;
      dataFactory.getData().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        vm.dataArr = result;
      });
  })
```

Ben Nadel gives a nice explanation of this issue [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2835-normalizing-untrusted-deferred-promise-values-for-the-digest-lifecycle-in-angularjs.htm).